# AWS SSM encounter an error 403 upon using session manager CLI plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-ssm, access-keys

What's wrong with my configuration? I'm getting this error message upon accessing my AWS Instance on my local ubuntu using AWS SSM or Session Manager Plugin for AWS CLI.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to access my AWS EC2 Instance on my local ubuntu machine.

Were not allowed to use pemfile for security reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognize your screenshot as part of the SSO account selection webpage.

Since you're using SSO, you must specify session token.  `aws configure` does not prompt for it.  So that command will not be sufficient for configuration - which is why it's not in the instructions.

Setting key, secret, and session token every time you SSO in is quite a pain.  I would strongly recommend doing this instead:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html

That works with aWS CLI v2 as well as just about every SDK.  I use it every day.